# pic gallery with table (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a picture gallery. I am trying to create a table through scripting.

Everything working fine but the pics are not visible in `td`:

```
<doctype html> <html>
<head> </head>

<body>
<table border="1" align="center"> 

<script>
var cont= new Array("pic1.jpg","pic2.jpg","pic3.jpg","pic4.jpg","pic5.jpg","pic6.jpg","pic7.jpg","pic8.jpg","pic9.jpg","pic10.jpg","pic11.jpg","pic13.jpg","pic14.jpg","pic15.jpg","pic16.jpg")
var col=5;
var ro=3;
v=0;

for (i=0; i<ro; i++)
{
        document.write("<tr>")
        for (j=0; j<col; j++)
        {
            document.write("<td id='d' width='150px' height='150px'>  </td>")
            h=document.getElementById("d")          
            h.src= cont[v]; 
        }
        document.write ("</tr>")

}

document.title="no error"


</script>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 1) Please, correct the code formatting. 
2) All td's has the same id, change it

Answer (score 1):

It is not showing because you're adding a `src` attribute to a `td`, but it should be used in an `img` tag instead.

Why not add the attribute directly in the html string instead of trying to get by id after creation?

```
document.write("<td id='d' width='150px' height='150px'><img src='" + cont[v] + "' /></td>")
```

Or even better, maybe:

```
document.write("<td><img src='" + cont[v] + "' width='150px' height='150px' /></td>")
```

You also need to increment your `v` variable somewhere, or you will get only the first image, try using `cont[v++]`.

Answer (score 0):

When you add several elements with the same id the function:

```
document.getElementById("d")
```

returns unexpected results.

The other thing that you doing wrong is settings src to td tag not the img tag.